# Crash in com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer.detect

Tags: android, vision, android-vision

I have a crash in com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer.detect which I am trying to get some progress on. The crash is non repro; reported from field; by a very small percentage. Our code analysis and testing has not revealed anything. To make progress I was hoping to look at the library 'code'. Given that Android is open source, where can I possibly start looking for code that comprises the classes/libs given in the source code below?

The line 28328 pipeline.cc:208] Check failed: ValidateInputPreviewFrame is giving me some hope; that we can backtrace the source of our error.

```
F0000 00:00:<PHONE_NUMBER>.948011   28328 pipeline.cc:208] Check failed: ValidateInputPreviewFrame(config_, timestamp_us, current_frame_timestamp_us_, raw_data, width, height, format, rotation) is OK (INVALID_ARGUMENT: Input timestamp: 227360497000 is earlier than the timestamp of the last frame: 227360500000
```

---

pid: 0, tid: 28328 >>> com.octro.teenpatti <<<

backtrace:
#00  pc 0x000000000008d394  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
#01  pc 0x0000000000782554  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#02  pc 0x0000000000782940  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#03  pc 0x00000000007826f4  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#04  pc 0x0000000000782428  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#05  pc 0x00000000007829e8  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#06  pc 0x00000000005d2190  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#07  pc 0x00000000004f34b8  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk
#08  pc 0x0000000000461554  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148)
#09  pc 0x000000000020be84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+11140)
#10  pc 0x0000000000053402  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk (so.f+310)
#11  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#12  pc 0x000000000005327c  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk (so.e)
#13  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#14  pc 0x000000000007d5d4  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk (aza.a+88)
#15  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#16  pc 0x00000000000367c8  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000012a/dl-MlkitOcrCommon.optional_230914100400.apk (bp.onTransact+40)
#17  pc 0x0000000000bb2ae8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Binder.transact+152)
#18  pc 0x000000000020b74c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+9292)
#19  pc 0x000000000002ed06  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000130/dl-VisionOcrDynamite.integ_231000400100000.apk (bo.b+14)
#20  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#21  pc 0x0000000000069662  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000130/dl-VisionOcrDynamite.integ_231000400100000.apk (aqs.f+22)
#22  pc 0x000000000020b074  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
#23  pc 0x00000000000430d2  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000130/dl-VisionOcrDynamite.integ_231000400100000.apk (lr.b+50)
#24  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#25  pc 0x0000000000042fec  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000130/dl-VisionOcrDynamite.integ_231000400100000.apk (lr.a+104)
#26  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#27  pc 0x000000000002ee44  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000130/dl-VisionOcrDynamite.integ_231000400100000.apk (bp.onTransact+40)
#28  pc 0x0000000000bb2ae8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (android.os.Binder.transact+152)
#29  pc 0x000000000020b74c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+9292)
#30  pc 0x0000000000c6030a  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@~~pA6jJuE0tuQw0_nVaLD-ZQ==@com.octro.teenpatti-PY5NfCaS_JPzMAIVEI3cig==@base.apk@classes.vdex (com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzb.zza+14)
#31  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#32  pc 0x0000000000c5f298  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@~~pA6jJuE0tuQw0_nVaLD-ZQ==@com.octro.teenpatti-PY5NfCaS_JPzMAIVEI3cig==@base.apk@classes.vdex (com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzac.zza+28)
#33  pc 0x000000000020b074  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540)
#34  pc 0x0000000000c5f72a  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@~~pA6jJuE0tuQw0_nVaLD-ZQ==@com.octro.teenpatti-PY5NfCaS_JPzMAIVEI3cig==@base.apk@classes.vdex (com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzan.zza+52)
#35  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#36  pc 0x0000000000cbbc80  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@~~pA6jJuE0tuQw0_nVaLD-ZQ==@com.octro.teenpatti-PY5NfCaS_JPzMAIVEI3cig==@base.apk@classes.vdex (com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer.detect+448)
#37  pc 0x000000000020a254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924)
#38  pc 0x00000000010eb384  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@~~pA6jJuE0tuQw0_nVaLD-ZQ==@com.octro.teenpatti-PY5NfCaS_JPzMAIVEI3cig==@base.apk@classes.vdex (org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity$4$1.run+20)
#39  pc 0x00000000003fd7c0  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+80)
#40  pc 0x0000000000457b6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+556)
#41  pc 0x0000000000484e54  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+156)
#42  pc 0x0000000000484b20  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesart::ArtMethod*(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+400)
#43  pc 0x00000000005ce334  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1684)
#44  pc 0x00000000000f5298  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
#45  pc 0x000000000008ebdc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)

Answer (score 0):

Google vision is now deprecated you can use MLKit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).